# Question about algebraically closed fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra

True/false

Q:Algebraically closed field must be of characteristic zero.

I think answer is false.This statement is not true for finite field.

Comment: There are algebraically closed fields of any characteristic $p$. A finite field is never algebraically closed.

Comment: Why do you never accept an answer ? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 3):

For any field $F$, there is an algebraically closed field $K$ that contains $F$. In particular, there are algebraically closed fields of any characteristic.

However, no finite field is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 1):

Take the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and then take its algebraic closure (which exists why? - Exercise!). This will be an algebraically closed field, which contains $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as a subfield, i.e. an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.